# Callback in React Native onPress for a Method

Tags: react-native

I would like to make a callback after a method in onPress

I learned how to do this :

```
this.setState({someState: 'value'}, () => alert('I'm a callback'));
```

Now I would like to do like this :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.myMethod() // And then have a callback here} />
```

How can I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to pass the callback as an argument

```
myMethod=(callback)=>{
  //logic of mymethod
  if(callback)
  { 
    callback();
  }
}

//inside render
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.myMethod(callback)} />
```

This way the callback would be executed once the logic of myMethod is completed.